# Finding maximum element in an array - is it that you will call greedy algorithm or brute force algorithm or both?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, brute-force, greedy

Suppose an array of integers is given:

```
{1,3,2,4,6,5,2} 
- MAX: 6
```

Using **Brute force**, finding maximum element in this is to observe every element (*each element is a candidate for the solution*), thus searching entire search space.

Considering **Greedy approach**, we will modify the maximum element at each element of the array if necessary. Thus a local optimal choice will eventually lead to global optimal choice.

Are brute force and greedy approach similar here? So what exacty the difference between two algos in general?

**Approach:**

**Brute force** - Starting from first element - 1 taking it as max. Now considering each and every next element in array - entire search space. Choosing maximum at each step if necessary. This is brute force.

**Greedy Algorithm** - starting from nothing, taking first element - taking it max as 1. Then considering second element - 3, making local optimal choice between 1 and 3- taking 3 as maximum. And so on for other elements. At last, we will have 6 as maximum element- the global optimal choice.

How will you exactly tell the difference between the two algos in general?

Comment: You haven't shown an approach, you've described them both. Your question is unclear

Comment: Brute force - Starting from first element -  1 taking it as max. Now considering each and every next element in array - entire search space. Choosing maximum at each step if necessary. This brute force. 



Greedy Algorithm - starting from nothing, taking first element - taking it max as 1. Then considering second element - 3, making local optimal choice between 1 and 3- taking 3 as maximum. And so on for other elements. At last, we will have 6 as maximum element- the global optimal choice.

Comment: I don't know what your goals are, but this problem is a bad one to compare and contrast brute force vs. greedy strategies. Your greedy algorithm could also be the description for divide & conquer strategies.

Comment: I was confused as to what I should call the above problem - a brute force or greedy. It raised some doubts in me. May be the above should be categorized as both brute force and greedy.

Comment: If you will see this question -[link](http://codeforces.com/contest/463/problem/B) (http://codeforces.com/contest/463/problem/B). Again there is a problem between deciding if it belongs to greedy or brute force paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the maximum element in an unsorted array will require the brute-force approach.

There are ways of minimizing the complexity of this operation by using data-structures such as heaps, which sort the data as it is being added to the structure.

Comment: But my question is - Is using brute force in above problem equivalent to a greedy algortihm solution ?

Comment: Yes, the two approaches that you've mentioned are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

A greedy algorithm might look something like this:

```
pick random starting point
if any of the two neighbors have higher value:
    move to the neighbor
else:  
    return value at current point
```

I would not call the linear scan of an array a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Array: {1,3,2,4,6,5,2}

So if you start at the second element - '3'. Then going by your approach, the two neighbors of 3 - 1 and 2, will not have larger value than 3 and so answer will be 3 but maximum is 6.

Comment: Right, the greedy approach gives a local maximum, which may be different from the global maximum.  I'm not claiming that this algorithm solves your problem.

Comment: But the greedy approach that I have mentioned in the question is correct. Isn't it ? A linear scan if we are making locally optimal choices may be considered as greedy. It's just that I am unable to differentiate Brute Force and Greedy algorithms clearly in the above problem.